# How to create a thread safe generator that reads one giant dataframe in Keras mode fit_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, thread-safety, deep-learning, keras

Keras newbie here. I am doing some deep learning experiment (keras 2.x, tensorflow as background, python3.5) on a very large CSV file.

After loading CSV into Pandas dataframe, I need to read dataframe to transform the data into X_train, y_train/label. Because the X_train after the transformation is huge that can't fit into memory. I started using generator and model.fit_generator().  I have learned that by creating a thread-safe generator that I could use multiple workers and use_multiprocessing=True so that it's more efficient. However, inside generator it always reads the same dataframe in my case, I wonder how I could make it thread-safe in a sense that same data/row won't be read and yield by multiple generator instance?

My current generator implementation without thread-safe is like:

```
    data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=0, delimiter="\t", quoting=3, encoding="utf-8")
    y = data.label
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, y, test_size=0.2)

    def data_genereator(data, batch_size):
        num_rows = int(data.shape[0])
        # Initialize a counter
        counter = 0
        while True:
            for content, label in zip(data['content'], data['label']):
                X_train[counter%batch_size] = transform(content)
                y_train[counter%batch_size] = np.asarray(label)
                counter = counter + 1
                if(counter%batch_size == 0):
                    yield X_train, y_train
    training_generator = data_genereator(X_train, batch_size=1024)
    validation_generator = data_genereator(X_test, batch_size=1024)

   model = Sequential()
   model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(1000, 2400), return_sequences=False, 
   kernel_initializer='he_normal', dropout=0.15, recurrent_dropout=0.15, implementation=2))
   model.add(Dropout(0.3))
   model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

   model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit_generator(training_generator,
                       steps_per_epoch=8000,
                       validation_data=validation_generator, 
                       epochs=3, 
                       verbose=1,
                       workers=1,
                       use_multiprocessing=False,
                       validation_steps=2000)
```

I might be totally wrong but want to get your feedback on my understanding of works and use_multiprocessing parameter, is that multiple generator instances (like **producer**) will be launched to feed the data into a queue what was create/maintained by model.fit_generator() function, meanwhile data will be grabbed from queue into GPU for training(**consumer**). If training with GPU is not bottleneck, then the more data could be yield/produced by generator, the faster the overall process would be. I learned by default the max_queue_size = 10, how to define the proper max_queue_size once the generator is thread-safe?

Also, is there a way to measure weather the bottleneck is generator(producer) or GPU training(consumer)?
I use verbose = 1 to print the status bar, as well as how many rows a single thread generator yield.  Right now it always like:

> number of rows yield = (max_queue_size + number of steps has been processed) * batch_size

So i can't really tell if the generator is too slow to feed in data or if the GPU training is bottleneck, seems like later as the queue is always full, but I am not certain, any insight is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Keras recommends that you use a `Sequence` for this: https://keras.io/utils/

Comment: Or as mentioned [here](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-generator-multiprocessing.html) , use a simple locking mechanism to make the iterator/generator thread safe

Comment: Thanks Daniel, again :)  I didn't find too much example other than https://gist.github.com/alxndrkalinin/6cc4228e9178ec4af7b2696a0d1ad5a1,  will try it out.  As I am using model.fit_generator(), I noticed that in epoch 2, the accuracy started dropping continuously since half steps has been completed, it dropped very badly all the way down and never goes up again. Could you give some insight about this situation?  Is this overfitting within same epoch?   Could you please also correct me on my understanding of Queue, workers with multiprocessing, and throughput bottleneck measurement?

Comment: Thanks Scarecrow. I had tried the example and didn't make it work. I found that the same row was yield twice by two generators within the same epoch, which probably due to the flaw of my code.  I also have a doubt about locking mechanism - if at time point A  it's locked by one generator 1, meaning none other generators can do anything to that file, so it's actually still "single thread"? how would throughput be increased by this? Sorry for my stupid question :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code keeps yielding all of X_train and y_train each time your counter reaches a batch size. It should only yield one batch at a time:

```
if(counter%batch_size == 0):
   yield X_train[counter-batch_size:counter], y_train[counter-batch_size:counter]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. In my code I actually used following code, is this also correct? 
 
for content, label in zip(data['content'], data['label']):

                X_train[counter%batch_size] = transform(content)

                y_train[counter%batch_size] = np.asarray(label)

                counter = counter + 1

                if(counter%batch_size == 0):

                    yield X_train, y_train

Comment: This way it always yield a np array whose row_count = batch_size without giving the global index for each row that was yield. e.g in first batch it yield np[512, 1000, 2400] array, in second batch it also yield np[512, 1000, 2400] array but index in second batch starts counted from 0 again. this will lose the global index for given row, so it's not right?